# set HTMLTextArea with text containing special caracteres

Tags: html, vb.net

I'm programming in vb.net; I stored mail body (with html caracteres and tags like  for exemple) in a database. In a grid, when an email subject is clicked, I'd like to show the message in an HTMLTextArea. Here is a piece of code:

```
         Try
            If e.CommandName = "Read" Then
            Dim obj As New Mail(e.CommandArgument)
            obj.AddMailArchive(currentUser.ID)
            champMail.InnerHtml = obj.Body
```

How could I put that text to the HTMLTextArea? The text just appears like a simple text and not as an HTML text: I tried InnerText, InnerHTML or Value Properties in vain.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a way to show the message: an HTML div instead of an HTMLTextArea.

Thanks to Karl Anderson, I used his tip by replacing the TextBox by a Div and used, then, the InnerHTML property of the Div, and it works!

Answer (score 0):

The ASP.NET `TextBox` control has a `TextMode` property which can be set to `Multiline` that will make a regular textbox behave like an HTML text area, like this:

```
<asp:TextBox id="TextBox1" runat="server" TextMode="Multiline" />
```

Code-behind (`Page_Load` or other event):

```
TextBox1.Text = "<b>AUTOMATIc NOTIFICATION</b><br /><br /><b>Notification sent on:</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;08-07-2013 09:02:41 AM<br /><br />We inform you that a new course is available.<br /><br/><b>title:</b> Intro to C#";
```

Comment: thanks, but let me tell you. here is a part of the text: "<b>AUTOMATIc NOTIFICATION</b><br /><br /><b>Notification sent on:</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;08-07-2013  09:02:41 AM<br /><br />We inform you that a new course is available.<br /><br/><b>title:</b> Intro to C#". So how could I put that text to the textBox, please?

Comment: thanks for your help; I did it with a div instead of a textBox ('cause it didn't work). I used then the InnerHTML property of the div.